# Как зафиксировать контейнер для строк в одном положении?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

У меня есть контейнер item, в котором на одной строке расположены по порядку название, дата и статус, заданные с помощью

```
.title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Ниже расположено описание. Соответственно, таких контейнеров может располагаться много. Но если статус у них будет разный (в моем случае "In Progress" и "Done" => ширина блока меняется) и отсюда строка даты у каждой колонки едет
Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы дата была фиксированной и ровной, вне зависимости от статуса[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно задать для статуса **flex-basis**, но он опять-таки будет фиксированным. Насколько я понимаю, это плохая практика для **flex-basis** задавать px
https://codepen.io/fiorgf/pen/QWJggzM

Comment: Может вы воспользуетесь более нормальным способом для такой верстки? Используйте `<table>`...

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>document</title>
<style>
table {border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}
td:nth-child(n+3) {width: 200px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Название</th>
<th>Дата</th>
<th>Статус</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name 1</td>
<td>07.07.2023</td>
<td>In Progress</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name 2</td>
<td>07.07.2023</td>
<td>Done</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот так это можно реализовать